# How to process text lines in bash extracting numbers for each matching line?

Tags: bash

I have a `grep` that returns me a text file in the following format:

```
filename1.txt:14
filename1.txt:17
filename2.txt:10
```

I want to write a scripts so that I can generate a text in the following format:

```
filename1.txt 14 17
filename2.txt 10
```

How can I extract those numbers in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`awk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) for this:

```
previous_command | awk -F':' '{x[$1] = x[$1]" "$2} END {for (f in x) print f""x[f]}'
```

If `previous_command` produces:

```
filename1.txt:14
filename1.txt:17
filename2.txt:10
```

Then the result will be:

```
filename2.txt 10
filename1.txt 14 17
```

If you also want the result to be alphabetically ordered then just pipe that to `sort`:

```
previous_command | awk -F':' '{x[$1] = x[$1]" "$2} END {for (f in x) print f""x[f]}' | sort
```

Result:

```
filename1.txt 14 17
filename2.txt 10
```